# ngTagsInput 3.2.0 array insert with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, arrays

I am a beginner and I am trying to save ng-tags-input version 3.2.0 which supports use-strings. I am trying to save items from the tags via PHP.

I went through the implode, but it does not show or save anything. 
Without implode, items appear in a string.

I don't know what the problem is. Do you think I maybe using array wrong?

Please help me. I am struggling with this for 5 days already...

[AngularJS]

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" use-strings="true"></tags-input>
```

[controller.js]

```
$scope.tags = [];
$http.post("insert.php", {
tags : $scope.tags})
```

[insert.PHP]

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$tags_array_raw = $data->tags;
$tags_array = implode(", ", $tags_array_raw);
foreach($tags_array as $tags_mid) {
    $tags.="$tags_mid";
}
$conn->query("INSERT INTO `table` (tags) VALUES('$tags')") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Other than array type, normal INPUT is being saved well.

I am lost where to go from here and please advise me on this 'tags-input array save' problem. I hope this also helps the others.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

instead of saving the field as json or a comma separated list, which would break the first rule of normalisation (1NF), consider creating another table for the "array" similar to this:

```
create table child(
    parent_id int
    field ...
```

)

that way you can get the data back by doing this:

```
select * from child where parent_id = ...
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But, I need to save that as it is. I think the syntax or expression is not incorrect, but not working. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: then I guess you'll probably want to json_encode the $tags, but I still think that's a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will take note to that! Hope this helps the others as well.

Comment: I'm glad I can help! :)